# WPSE Community Day!

Tags: discussion

Thanks to the positive responses to holding [Community Activities](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4247/monthly-community-activities) we've decided to get the ball rolling and start things off with some local site maintenance. *Maybe* not the most interesting of events to start off with but it's a good way to gauge participation, an easy thing to teach, and great for new users to gain reputation! Now I know what you're thinking

> But Mr. McGee, how can I help?

I'm glad you asked! There are many ways you can help!

- Our answer rate is currently at [~72% ( Rank 144 )](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4194/7355). There's 19,409 unanswered questions that need looked at, that's a more than a bunch. Some have answers that may need tested and upvoted if they're accurate ( this counts as "answered" ).
- There's [new questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions) and [old questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions?page=1393&sort=newest) along with some of the [most upvoted answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3Aanswer) which may need edited for clarification, formatting, or any other issues.
- [Our review queue](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/review) has over 100 questions, answers, and edits that need to be looked at and cast judgement upon so grab a gavel!
- There are [many tags](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tags) without any kind of description, most of which are WordPress functions which can be referenced from the [The Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/) or [The Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/).
- Some tags aren't necessary and could probably be closed since they're either too broad or generally off-topic and don't have many questions tagged to them. These tags include...
  [netbeans](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/netbeans) [plugin-events-calendar](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin-events-calendar) [post-installation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/post-installation) [profiling](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/profiling) [ide](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ide) [sms](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sms) [social-connect](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-connect) [books](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books) [custom-write-panel](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/custom-write-panel) [stackoverflow](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) [google-plus](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-plus) [tumblr](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tumblr) [plugin-magic-fields](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin-magic-fields) [google-chrome](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome) [plugin-syntaxhighlighter](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin-syntaxhighlighter) [flash](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flash) [code](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code) [coding](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coding) [create](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/create) [foreach](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foreach) [php](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/php) [handling](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/handling) [customization](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/customization) [functions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functions) [modifications](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modifications) [next](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/next) [previous](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/previous) [recursive](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recursive) [scale](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scale) [troubleshooting](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/troubleshooting)

Next Saturday ( September 10th ) we'll use the general "[The Loop](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6/the-loop)" chatroom to tackle some of the above tasks, work together to answer some of the tougher long-standing WPSE questions, discuss ways we can make this community better, and generally goof around. This will be an all day event so come and go as you please!

Comment: Thanks for specifying what you actually mean by [next saturday](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3841/which-day-does-next-tuesday-refer-to) ;-)

Comment: Do we need a separate room for that? I think [The Loop](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6/the-loop) is good enough.

Comment: You might want to set a start and end date and link to some [time converter](http://www.thetimezoneconverter.com/event_link.html).

Comment: I'm away on holidays atm and will be in planes most of the 10th, so I wish you guys all the best!! Looking forward to seeing the outcome of the event and taking part in a future one

Answer (score 9):

To be honest, I think that's a bit too much for one event. Let me take the liberty to propose narrowing it down to this:

**Let's take on the answer rate. Work on unanswered questions, even if they are stupid or mildly off topic (we all know our php, css and jquery). Post the link in chat once you're done. Invite others to review and +1 it if it looks okay.**

The latter part is essential, I think. It gives interaction between members and also some immediate gratification. It's frustrating to answer old questions and end with neither personal nor communal gain, as the 0 votes answer slides into oblivion without butching your rep or the answer rate.

Then next event we can butcher some tags.

Comment: The above I've posted are all options should anyone not have the expertise yet to answer questions thoroughly or get bored with one venture. I agree attacking the answer rate is high priority ( that's where most my time will be during the event ) but it's not the only thing that helps. I don't expect to kill all the listed tags or completely clear review queue but as an all day event, spending 5 minutes to add a tag description or 10 minutes to clear their 20 review votes will certainly help in the long run!

Answer (score 5):

Tagging off of [cjbj](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/users/75495/cjbj)'s post, even before I found out about this event, I've been tackling questions that have technically been answered within the question itself or comments ([see example](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/237883/98212)).

This will definitely put some closure on those questions that haven't been confirmed by the OP as *resolved* even though they have.

The same goes for questions that has an answered posted by the OP on the same day, but they cannot accept their answer due to the rule of having to wait two days before the OP can accept their own answer. This results in the OP forgetting to accept their answer after two days ([see example](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/237839))